# Select last remaining value in dropdown in change() event on Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I have created a dropdown in Angular and used change() event to capture the selected value. 
Ex:the dropdown has Age,gender and Nationality. If I select Age,it will display some content and remove the Age option in the dropdown.

This part worked fine. Similarly I do the same for Gender too. Finally I have only Nationality.
I can't able to select the Nationality(last) field. Is there any other event for capturing this value?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" name="seg_id" (change)="changeShape($event.target)">
          <option disabled hidden [value]="selectUndefinedOptionValue">-- select --</option>
            <option *ngFor="let seg of segment" [value]="seg">
             {{seg}}
            </option>
        </select>
```